# Setting path for AHK's FileSelectFile function not working

Tags: autohotkey

My goal is to create a script that will allow me to paste images into a social media platform's new post instance. This platform allows pasting images from Clipboard.

My logic is:

1. Open the File Select modal with a specific default path.
2. Select a file by user.
3. Pass the selected object to the Clipboard.
4. Send the Paste command back into the Post instance.

I was able to complete all of this; the only issue I'm having is setting the absolute starting path of the File Select modal; no matter what I do, or how I pass the absolute path, it seems to always open the path of the last physical action outside the script, in other words, if I physically opened a Explorer from Windows itself or any other app, it will use that path, instead of the one I mentioned in the script; it's been driving me nuts. I've rebooted the script, refreshed everything, cleared cache, did a rain dance.

Would love some assistance!

Here's my script:

```
^+x::

mypath := "C:\Users\MyComputerName\Downloads\SOCIAL-MEDIA\Images"

FileSelectFile, SelectedFile, 3, %mypath%

if (SelectedFile = "")
    MsgBox, The user didn't select anything.
else

pToken := Gdip_Startup()
Gdip_SetBitmapToClipboard(pBitmap := Gdip_CreateBitmapFromFile(SelectedFile))
Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)
send ^v

return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting the third parameter to "2" aka "Path must exist," did the trick.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/FileSelectFile.htm